# Why rendezvous attempt failed on Gemini 4?

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, reference-frames

It is [said in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_4#Rendezvous_attempt), that

> On the first orbit, McDivitt attempted to rendezvous with the spent
>   Titan second stage. This was unsuccessful for a number of reasons:
>
> NASA engineers had not yet worked out the idiosyncrasies of orbital
>   mechanics involved in rendezvous,[citation needed] which are
>   counter-intuitive. Simply thrusting the spacecraft toward the target
>   changed its orbital altitude and velocity relative to the target. When
>   McDivitt tried this, he found himself moving away and downward, as the
>   retrograde thrust lowered his orbit, increasing his speed.

I don't understand this.

Is there any explanation, given in local reference frame? Referring "orbital altitude" referrers global reference frame and is OK. But any set can be possibly regarded in any reference frame. Local reference frame should be inertial with tidal, Coriolis and other forces.

How to describe the situation with this?

**UPDATE**

Suppose we are inside giant closed spacecraft like [Rama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama_%28spacecraft%29) or [O'Neill cylinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Neill_cylinder). This spacecraft is on Earth orbit, but we are inside and don't know this. We feel weightlessness. Now, If Rama is rotating, we can feel some non-inertial effects like centrifugal or Coriolis forces.

But suppose Rama is not rotating.

Then, the only strange thing we will feel is Earth tidal force. The tidal force mean that all objects will periodically distracted along axis, directed to (invisible) Earth.

So, you want to say, that McDivitt failed due to tidal forces?

Hard to believe.

Comment: Would http://space.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Comment: One way to check the validity of the tidal explanation would be to verify that the effect of the forces being discussed on a cloud of test particles is to distort the cloud without changing its volume. Another way might be to see if the effect scales like $r^{-3}$.

Comment: Note that in addition to tensile forces radially, tides impose constricting forces in the plane normal to the radius.

Comment: already answered on space exploration stack exchange: http://space.stackexchange.com/q/2476/